# puppet remote command execution without agent configuration

Tags: puppet

Which puppet module to used (How to configure), so that it can execute command in the remote machine, **without using any puppet agent**

[image]

for example from HOST-A, a puppet script to be executed and it takes the command and execute the command in **HOST-B**

what i know is the openssh keys can be used to exchange the login info, then after the command can be executed, what i'm missing is is there any module available that do this job, so that, just adding the command the same can be achieved

This is coming from the `ANsible` background

Answer (score 2):

You maybe looking for mcollective/live management feature of puppet which allows you to run ad-hoc commands on the nodes. However you will have to install mcollective agents on all the nodes being managed any ways.

If you compare it with Ansible, puppet does not support running ad-hoc commands inherently otherwise. It does not work over ssh like ansible does. Its not agentless by nature. You need puppet agent/apply to be installed and configured.

Comment: looks like we have to install the agent, even we use mcollective

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way of achieving this, but you can use `exec` to execute ssh with a command to run on another machine. The command to execute would be the [same as what you would use from the shell](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-running-commands-on-a-remote-host.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need jump out from the pit what you know about Ansible when thinking of puppet, they are different.

Puppet works for final status called [idempotency](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/introduction.html#idempotency), ansible is as batch ssh scripts.

The rest, @Gourav has been explained clearly.